# get indexpath from collectionView, sometime get the wrong indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

in `UItableView` we can use those code to get `indexPath` from a `UITableView`

```
extension UIView{  
  func getButtonIndexPath(tableView:UITableView) -> NSIndexPath{
            let buttonOriginInTableView = self.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
            return tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonOriginInTableView)!
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work so well in `UICollectionView`

```
extension UIView{
    func getIndexPath(uc:UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath?{
        let senderP = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.height / 2)
            let point : CGPoint = self.convertPoint(senderP, toView:uc)
            let ind = uc.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
            print("what i click is", point, ind)
        return ind
}
```

i put this in a button of a cell in `UICollectionView`

```
delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FavViewController.DelFavAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and the function is

```
    func DelFavAction(sender:UIButton){
    guard let indexPath = sender.getIndexPath(self.collectionView) else {
    return
    }
    print(indexPath)
}
```

but mostly get the wrong `indexPath.item`, how is that happening?

is something to do with this code?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return rectArr[indexPath.item].size
}
```

Comment: you want indexpath of cell whose cell is selected. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

you are write this line:

```
delBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FavViewController.DelFavAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

below write other line:

```
delBtn.tag = indexPath.item;
```

and get item:

```
func DelFavAction(sender:UIButton){
//        sender.tag to convert uibutton;
//  for objectvie C write: UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
}
```